# Prevent flycheck warning window

Tags: flycheck, warning

When flycheck finds too many warnings that do not fit in the mini-buffer, it opens up a window on a buffer named *Warnings* that looks something like this:

```
Warning (flycheck): Syntax checker python-pylint reported too many errors (665) and is disabled.
Use ‘M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-checker-error-threshold’ to
change the threshold or ‘C-u C-c ! x’ to re-enable the checker.
Warning (flycheck): Syntax checker python-pylint reported too many errors (665) and is disabled.
Use ‘M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-checker-error-threshold’ to
change the threshold or ‘C-u C-c ! x’ to re-enable the checker.
Warning (flycheck): Syntax checker python-pylint reported too many errors (659) and is disabled.
Use ‘M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-checker-error-threshold’ to
change the threshold or ‘C-u C-c ! x’ to re-enable the checker.
Warning (flycheck): Syntax checker python-pylint reported too many errors (667) and is disabled.
Use ‘M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-checker-error-threshold’ to
change the threshold or ‘C-u C-c ! x’ to re-enable the checker.
```

**How to stop this window from opening?** It is extremely obtrusive and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a better answer than this one: Use `M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-checker-error-threshold` to change the threshold. Mine is currently set to 400.

If someone has a better solution, I gladly remove this answer.